# Copiar texto con agregación de adicional texto

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente coódigo este copia el contenido de un input sin formato, pero hay alguna forma para que copie y al copiado agregue un texto adicional.

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Copiar Texto</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <textarea id="textareaComentarioIncidencia"></textarea>
            <button id="botonPortapapelesIncidencias">Clipboard</button>
        </body>
    </html>

    <script lang="Javascript">
    var textareaIncidencia = 
    document.getElementById("textareaComentarioIncidencia");
    var copyIncidencia = 
    document.getElementById("botonPortapapelesIncidencias")
        copyIncidencia.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        textareaIncidencia.select();
        var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: has intendtado con element.innerText += "contenido extra"?

Comment: element.innerText += "contenido extra" ¿pero donde iría eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opcion es crear la ilusión cambiando temporalmente el valor del textarea de la siguiente manera:

```js
var textareaIncidencia =
 document.getElementById("textareaComentarioIncidencia");
 var copyIncidencia =
 document.getElementById("botonPortapapelesIncidencias")
 copyIncidencia.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 let aux = textareaIncidencia.value;
 textareaIncidencia.value = "hello\n" + textareaIncidencia.value;
 textareaIncidencia.value += "\nworld";
 textareaIncidencia.select();
 var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
 textareaIncidencia.value = aux;
 });
```

```html
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Copiar Texto</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <textarea id="textareaComentarioIncidencia"></textarea>
 <button id="botonPortapapelesIncidencias">Clipboard</button>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Es excelente... ¿Pero si quisiera que el "\nhello world" estuviera antes del copiado o el copiado en medio?

Comment: con .value del textarea obtienes el texto del textarea, eso lo puedes manipular como quieras, el texto modificado puedes ponerlo en el mismo textarea y copiarlo, y al luego regresar el valor del textarea a su valor inicial. Como opción es que tengas un textarea auxiliar donde ingreses en su .value el tecto modoficado y lo copies de ahí. Modifiqué la respuesta como sería el texto al medio.